# SQLite delete query not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a simple delete query which delete records based on Created date

```
int result = db.delete(TableName,"CreatedDate=?",new String[] { "STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', DATETIME('now'))" });
```

The above query is not working.

But when i am writing the same in this format

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE CreatedDate =STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y',DATE('Now'))
```

Now its working.

i am not able to understand why one is working and another is not. What i am missing?

And my another question is behind the curtain what query is generated by this line

```
db.delete(TableName,"CreatedDate=?",new String[] { "STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', DATETIME('now'))" });
```

Please enlighten me!

Thanks

Comment: Your first query looks for tables where CreatedDate is literally the string `"STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', DATETIME('now'))"` - it doesn't evaluate the function. (This is, in fact, the entire point of parameterized queries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `?` for binding literals. For example, string literals you'd write in `'single quotes'` in SQL. You cannot use `?` for binding expressions like `STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y',DATE('Now'))`.

Essentially when you try to bind the expression but it is bound as a string literal, the query becomes

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE CreatedDate ='STRFTIME(''%d-%m-%Y'',DATE(''Now''))'
```